# How to replace the recursive subpattern "(?1)" in python regex syntax?

Tags: python, regex, recursion

I was developing a regex pattern to match valid parenthesis. Suddenly python regex engine does not support recursion. In paticular the `(?1)` syntax.

Is there a way to translate this pcre pattern to python regex pattern?

https://regex101.com/r/SSOlWX/1

```
^(\((?1)?\)(?1)?)$
```

Comment: Use it with PyPi `regex` module. `re` does not support subroutines, nor recursion.

Comment: and it is equal to `^(\((?1)?\))+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was said in the comments, the standart `re` module is not so powerful.

You can read more about the functionality lack [here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-python.html).

The [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) can provide you with all the functionality you need and you do not need to translate your regex pattern.